# Черное фото при снимке с веб камеры, телеграм бот

Tags: python, python-2.x, telegram-bot, python-2.7, telegram

Пишут бота для телеграм, написал функцию отправки фото с вебкамеры, все работает, и есть одно но, фото приходит полностью черное, лампочка загорается на вебке, фото приходит, но полностью черное. В чем проблема?
Вот код

```
from SimpleCV import Image, Camera

elif command == '/snap':
            bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'typing')
            cam = Camera()
            img = cam.getImage()
            img.save('snap.jpg')
            bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'upload_photo')
            bot.sendDocument(chat_id, open('snap.jpg', 'rb'))
            os.remove('snap.jpg')
```

Comment: 1. Для начала убедитесь, что сама камера работает. Можете ли вы получить нормальное изображение с неё без питона (например, в скайпе или средствами ОС)? 2. Потом попробуйте запустить скрипт без последней строчки, после чего найдите на диске получившийся файл snap.jpg и посмотрите, что в нём. Является ли изображение в нём полностью чёрным? Если на оба вопроса ответ - "да", то, видимо какие-то проблемы с работой библиотеки SimpleCV и нужно копать в этом направлении.

Comment: И вот ещё что я нашёл по вашей проблеме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109245/simplecv-webcam-black-image Похоже, камере после инстанцирования объекта Camera() нужно немного времени, прежде чем она будет готова. Попробуйте воспользоваться ответами из того вопроса.

Comment: @Александр, Нет не помогло, теперь фото отправляются боту без остановки

Comment: А что именно вы сделали? Покажите новый код. Какие именно фото отправляются без остановки - чёрные или нормальные?

Comment: import time
from SimpleCV import Camera
cam = Camera()
r = g = b = 0
while r + g + b < 0.01:
    img = cam.getImage()
    r, g, b = img[img.width/2, img.height/2]
    print("r: {} g: {} b: {}".format(r,g,b))
    time.sleep(1)
img.save(file_name)

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, а то без отступов ничего не разобрать. И этот код у вас вообще ничего боту не отправляет. Вы код не целиком привели?